# Getting 403 status code with GET request on Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, http, server, python-requests

I'm encountering an issue with a Python script deployed as an Azure Function, which performs GET requests to URLs. The script works as expected for most URLs I've tested, but for certain ones, such as [https://nationworldnews.com/mercedes-benz-improves-driver-experience-with-azure-openai-service/#:~:text=Mercedes-Benz%20announced%20that%20they%20have%20started%20integrating%20ChatGPT,MBUX%20voice%20assistant%20even%20more%20intuitive%20and%20conversational](https://nationworldnews.com/mercedes-benz-improves-driver-experience-with-azure-openai-service/#:%7E:text=Mercedes-Benz%20announced%20that%20they%20have%20started%20integrating%20ChatGPT,MBUX%20voice%20assistant%20even%20more%20intuitive%20and%20conversational), it returns a 403 HTTP status code when executed in Azure Functions. However, when I run the same script locally against this URL, it successfully returns a 200 status code. Upon inspecting the request headers in both scenarios, they are identical.

Sharing only the relevant bit.

```py
def send_request(url, headers):
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    return response.status_code
```

Could someone explain why this discrepancy occurs and suggest a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below headers and got the expected response while accessing it in function app.

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import requests

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    
    response = requests.get("https://nationworldnews.com/mercedes-benz-improves-driver-experience-with-azure-openai-service/#:~:text=Mercedes-Benz%20announced%20that%20they%20have%20started%20integrating%20ChatGPT,MBUX%20voice%20assistant%20even%20more%20intuitive%20and%20conversational", headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return func.HttpResponse(body=response.text, status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse("Failed...", status_code=response.status_code)
```

**requirements.txt**-

```
azure-functions
requests
```

**Output**-

[image]

Add the headers, you will get the result too.

Comment: I am using this user-agent header value `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36` and getting 403 status code on Azure.

Comment: Invoke the Url in browser and check `User-Agent` in the headers in inspect like [this](https://i.imgur.com/hECMZLZ.png)

Comment: @Coder_H were you able to invoke the url from function app?

Comment: I checked the `User-Agent` in the browser and used that with the GET request but I am still getting 403 on Azure function app.

Comment: @Coder_H are you using my code?

Comment: I am passing the same headers in my code.

Comment: Can you please try once using my code